# Coldfusion Databases storing acting wonky

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfquery

So Coldfusion is acting wonky today. I can't seem to update DB.

For example if I try to query this :

```
<CFQUERY DATASOURCE="tr3" NAME="qryData2">
    SELECT *
    FROM UsersExpDataTR2
    WHERE session_id = 2 AND p1_id = 2 AND round = 3
</CFQUERY>
```

the qryData2.recordcount comes to equal 1.

But when I try to run this code

```
<CFQUERY DATASOURCE="tr3" NAME="uMatch">
    UPDATE UsersExpDataTR2
    SET p1_total = 13 AND p1_fine = 1
    WHERE session_id = 2 AND p1_id = 2 AND round = 3
</CFQUERY>
```

p1_total's value gets changed to 0 and p1_fine doesn't change from its original value.

I was going to stay late to restart the server but I was hoping I didn't have to and if someone could tell me the answer to these oddities?

NOTE: In the code itself I'm using variables to store and query [obviously]. I'm just using the numbers as a test.

UPDATE: They are all integer data types. Though I was also having problem with a double value in another situation.

Comment: Yes, they are all integer data types in this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax looks wonky to me :) Try this:

```
<CFQUERY DATASOURCE="tr3" NAME="uMatch">
    UPDATE UsersExpDataTR2
    SET p1_total = 13,
        p1_fine = 1
    WHERE session_id = 2 AND p1_id = 2 AND round = 3
</CFQUERY>
```

good luck number 1 we are all counting on you.

Comment: Sleep deprivation got the better of me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ha... I do that all the time - stare at something and just can't see it.